# Truncate words (chars) in vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How to truncate words or chars in VueJs 3 ? I searched some answers but didn't work for me.
For example if description words length more than 200 , it should display 200 words and ... at the end

What I tried so far..

```
<p>{{ announcement.description | truncate(200) }}</p>

<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
      announcement: {},
    }
  },
computed:{
    truncate(value, length) {
        if (value.length > length) {
            return value.substring(0, length) + "...";
        } else {
            return value;
          }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what should be the expected result? Please add it in question itself...

Comment: Sorry, I edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is a method, not a computed property. `A computed property is used to declaratively describe a value that depends on other values`. Move your code to methods and pass the argument with the length it should work.

```
    methods: {
       truncate(value, length) {
        if (value.length > length) {
            return value.substring(0, length) + "...";
        } else {
            return value;
          }
      }
   }
```

And just call this method from the template:

`truncate(announcement.description,200)`

You can read about correct usage of computed from here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html